# Blurry Images on my Website

Tags: images

After I upload images on my website, the images get blurry, particularly the ones with the text (please see the attached image where the right copy is local and left is in Media Library). I have checked solutions like disabling plugins or purging cache but that doesn't work. What could be the reason for that?

Update: I just changed the scale of my display from 125% to 100% on my Windows PC and it looks fine. Since I can't change user display, does this mean that I should only upload large image sizes? But then image might go beyond the allowable width.

If this conclusion is incorrect, is there anything else I can do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Text on images always look blurry when you view it at any other size than 100%. You can try saving them as an svg and using that, then you have to install a plugin that let's you upload svg's into your site.
Or can make it show text on the image but the images you have would take a lot of work. In a program like PPT you can zoom in and out because it is vector type stuff, but or .png, .jpg, .webp you blur the text by zooming. Most people have their monitor set to 100% I assume.
And no, I don't think larger images will help since the zoom does not enlarge the image in that way.

Comment: Can you please explain this part: "Or can make it show text on the image but the images you have would take a lot of work"

Comment: "Most people have their monitor set to 100% I assume", is this also true for 15.6 inches laptops and larger screens?

Comment: Having the monitor resolution set differently for smaller monitors will not make the text image blur, but setting The view to 125% or more than 100% is what causes the image to blur. So smaller monitors would see the image clearly larger monitors would see it clearly as well but if someone opened a browser and zoomed in on the web page then it would blur the image

Comment: If you convert the text that's on the image to actual text then you can zoom the image in and it won't blur as bad because the text is what blurs at different sizes. Being regular text on a web page it would not blur at all because text on a web page can zoom in and out without blurring